# Actionscript Webservice set result format as e4x

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, webservice-client

I'm trying to use Webservice component in my Flex 4 application.

I need to use this in Actioncript and not using MXML tags.

I'm able to invoke the WSDL operations successfully, but the resultFormat is Object by default.

How do I set it to e4x?

```
var lookupService:WebService = new WebService();
        lookupService.wsdl =url;
        lookupService.loadWSDL();

        lookupService.doLookup.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, lookupResultHandler);
        lookupService.doLookup.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultHandler);
        lookupService.doLookup(lookupString);
```

I tried to set the format by

```
lookupService.resultFormat = "e4x";
```

But this is not working. The calls are not even going through when I do this.

Can you please provide your suggestions for implementing this using AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the two [web](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) [service](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html) classes, you'll realize that resultFormat is not a property on either of them.  Resultset is a property on the [operations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AbstractService.html#operations) array.

If that doesn't help, you'll have to quantify "not working."  What isn't working?  Are you getting compile errors?  Are you getting runtime errors?  IS the data not being returned?  Is the data not be returned as XML?

You'll probably have to set this up in MXML and dissect the generated ActionScript to figure out the appropriate AS3 syntax.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. Created an instance of mx.rpc.soap.Operation and set the resultType as e4x. Then added this Operation into an Object array with the key as the operation name. And finally added the array to mx.rpc.AbstractService.operations.

Comment: mx.rpc.Operation was the 'class' I was looking for when writing this post.  I knew something like that must exist, I just didn't know what the name would be. Glad I helped you find the solution.